# Backoff not working in Apache Camel redelivery

Tags: jms, apache-camel

*(Camel version 2.14.1)*

I'm trying to get Camel to retry a msg to JMS (actually, MQ over JMS) using a backoff redelivery policy.  Here's what I've got:

```
errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
    .maximumRedeliveries(-1) 
    .useExponentialBackOff()
    .backOffMultiplier(2)
    .maximumRedeliveryDelay(30000)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

from("direct:in")
    .log("Sending message to MQ")
    .to("mq:MY_QUEUE?requestTimeout=1000");
```

My understanding of what should happen here is that the initial timeout will be 1000ms.  After that camel will wait 2000ms, then 4000ms, etc, until we get to 30000ms.

What's happening is that the message *is* retried, but at 1000ms every time.

What might I need to change in my code above to get the results that I'm looking for?

TIA

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but have you tried `transactionErrorHandler()` instead of `defaultErrorHandler()`?

Comment: I have not - that error handler requires a Spring TransactionTemplate which I do not use in my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out.

Here are the available configuration parameters that come into play (there are a lot).

On the error handler:

```
defaultErrorHandler()
    .maximumRedeliveries(-1) 
    .useExponentialBackOff()
    .backOffMultiplier(2)
    .maximumRedeliveryDelay(10000)
    .redeliveryDelay(500)
```

On the URI:

```
requestTimeout=400&
requestTimeoutCheckerInterval=300
```

There are a few scenarios here that act very differently

### Scenario A) JMS Server is down.

If the server is down then the fields from the URI (`requestTimeout` and `requestTimeoutCheckerInterval`) never come in to play.  Using the settings above you should see a retry delays of: 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 10000, 10000, 10000...

### Scenario B) JMS Server is up but consumer on the other side has not responded.

The requestTimeout value is never increased but the retry delay is.  So what you'll see is retry delays at: 900, 1400, 2400, 4400, 8400, 10400, 10400, 10400....

Why?  Because it takes 400ms (the `requestTimeout` to actually fail, after which the errorHandler timer kicks in).

### Gotchas !!!

- This little doozy here which is a log msg from a `*MessageListenerContainer`:

`Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'REPLY.A.QUEUE' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=67, maxAttempts=unlimited}`

This has *nothing to do* with retrying a message, it happens in another thread.  That `FixedBackOff` thing is a red herring.

- `requestTimeoutCheckerInterval` must always be <= `requestTimeout` or else the timeout will seemingly happen later than it's supposed to